# How to test method condition using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Mockito is used to mock object behavior but how do I check if the condition match if the method call is not an object call.

For example

```
boolean sameType= bloodType != null && bloodType.type.equals(patient.type);
if (sameType && transfusion(availability)) {
return true;
}

if (sameType && availability <= 0) {
reject.rejectBlood(info);
return false;
}
```

how do I cover those using mockito?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring at the method call

```
transfusion(availability)
```

Assuming also it is a private method, you cannot mock private methods using Mockito, but with PowerMock you can.

Anyway, unless it is legacy code that for any reason you cannot refactor, it's better you to avoid mocking private method calls because it leads to brittle and less readable tests.

Answer (score 0):

The above block of code is not standing in isolation - it is a method, or part of a method. That method is what you are testing. And there is nothing in this method that is not an object (or a boolean, I suppose).

So use Mockito to mock your `bloodType` object (or, if it's a simple enough object, make a real one yourself), and make sure that different blood types produce the expected results in your method. Also mock the `reject` object so you can be sure `rejectBlood()` is called with the right `info` object.

Once these things are mocked, you call your method and verify that it comes back with the right values and that the appropriate calls were made on your mocks.

Comment: Of what, exactly? Mockito's documentation is full of examples of how to use it; I'm assuming you've seen that, so I'm not sure how I can elaborate on my answer above.